# Deleting documents from cloudant db

Tags: cloudant

I need to delete specific documents from a cloudant database as illustrated below.
All documents are in the Json format:

```
{
    "_id":"abcd",
    "_rev":"1_efgh",
    "moduleName":"co",
    "userid":"knight",
    "stateType":"yout"
}
```

I want to delete all the documents for which the "userid" field *does not* match any of the values in a list of String values,
say
`["userid1", "userid2"]`

I am using *com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient* in Springboot.

Comment: As one solution, I have fetched all documents from the cloudant database as a list and iterated each document in the list to check for a match in the second list i.e, ["userid1", "userid2"]. And removed those documents that do not match _any_ of the values in the second list i.e, ["userid1", "userid2"]. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [view](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-views-mapreduce) to get the documents matching your criteria. Then you should perform a [bulk operation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-documents#deleting-documents-in-bulk) to delete the docs you've fetched before.
See also related question: [How to delete docs in Couch db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240881/how-to-delete-docs-in-couch-db)